# Eloquent attach() on a non-object error

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to attach a message to a conversation *(many-to-many)*, but I am getting an error. What am I missing?

**Pivot Table Schema**

`conversation_message` (`conversation_id`, `message_id`)

**Models**

```
class Conversation extends Eloquent
{
    public function messages()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Message', 'conversation_message', 'conversation_id', 'message_id');
    }
}

class Message extends Eloquent
{
    public function conversations()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Conversation', 'conversation_message', 'message_id', 'conversation_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$conversation = Conversation::find(1);
$message = Message::find(1);
$conversation->messages()->attach($message);
```

**Error**

```
Call to a member function attach() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are `return`s missing in both methods:

```
class Conversation extends Eloquent
{
    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Message', 'conversation_message', 'conversation_id', 'message_id');
    }
}

class Message extends Eloquent
{
    public function conversations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Conversation', 'conversation_message', 'message_id', 'conversation_id');
    }
}
```